# VBA to check whether the Cell has specific text

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find if "Payment info" is present in a cell that contains a string

If the criteria is met then the code should add new text *log* to the string

> "Supplier repay Payment info"

becomes

> "Supplier repay log Payment info"

Can any one help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `A1:A100`

```
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A100")
rng1.Replace "Payment info", "log Payment info", xlPart
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following UDF

```
Function CheckStr(cell As Range, srchString As String) As Boolean
    If InStr(UCase(cell.Value), UCase(srchString)) <> 0 Then
        CheckStr = True
    Else
        CheckStr = False
    End If
End Function
```

After re-reading your question i find it a little un-clear, the above code will search the value of a cell for certain string. I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: OP has asked for the original text to get changed if 'Payment Info' exists within it. You'll need VBA code to loop through the cells, testing the value and changing if required.

Answer (score 0):

If the original text to change always contains the text "Supplier repay Payment info", then you could simply use the Find & replace command (Ctrl-h). Find "Supplier repay Payment info" and replace with "Supplier repay log Payment info".